# Flutter | Disabling a button's onPressed till the end of current call

Tags: flutter

I have a `FloatingActionButton` that needs to be `disabled` when the user taps on it and wait until the result come back from `onPressed`

```dart
Widget _fab() {
  return FloatingActionButton(
    child: Icon(Icons.done),
    onPressed: _onFabTap,
  );
}

void _onFabTap() async {
  //Somehow disable the button here until the end of this method call
  await _viewModel.doneEditing();
  //now enable the button
}
```

P.S. I'm using `ChangeNotifier` with `Provider` for my state management.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An efficient way to do this is by using `ValueNotifier` since `setState` may impact app performance. Have a try with this

```
ValueNotifier _isLoadingNotifier = ValueNotifier(false);

Widget _fab() {
  return ValueListenableBuilder(
    valueListenable: _isLoadingNotifier,
    builder: (context, _isLoading, _) {
      return FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.done),
        onPressed: !_isLoading ? _onFabTap : null,
      );
    },
  );
}

void _onFabTap() async {
  _isLoadingNotifier.value = true;
  await _viewModel.doneEditing();
  _isLoadingNotifier.value = false;
}
```

Comment: This is a clever way. It's the same as using a Stateful widget for my button and calling setState on it, cause it only rebuilds the FloatingActionButton!

Comment: Exactly! You can build another StatefulWidget and call setState on it. The setState call will only apply on that widget and will not rebuild your entire page resulting in less memory consumption

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with setState as long as you keep the fab button a separate widget, but if your fab button is part of a bigger Widget you should consider moving it to a Separate widget or Consider using  `ValueNotifier` builder

```
bool buttonEnabled = true;
void _onFabTap() async {
  setState((){
    bool buttonEnabled = false;
  });
  //Somehow disable the button here until the end of this method call
  await _viewModel.doneEditing();
  setState((){
    bool buttonEnabled = true;
  });
}
```

and in build method

```
Widget _fab() {
  return FloatingActionButton(
    child: Icon(Icons.done),
    onPressed: buttonEnabled? _onFabTap:null,
  );
}
```

Comment: if the widget is too big, you should consider using ValueNotifier as @dm_tr answered

Comment: Your answer works, but the problem is that it rebuilds the whole UI along with the FAB.
I vote you up if you edit and state that it's better to make a Stateful widget and edit your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like :

```
Widget _fab() {
  return FloatingActionButton(
    child: Icon(Icons.done),
    onPressed:_viewModel.isLoading? null: _onFabTap,
  );
}
```

And then inside your `ChangeNotifier` do the following:

```
bool isLoading = false;
... doneEditing(...){
   isLoading = true;
   notifiyListeners();
   ...
   // api call
   ...
   isLoading = false;
   notifiyListeners();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool isLoading = false;
ontap() async {
if(!isLoading){
isLoading = true;
var rsponse = await asyncTask();
isLoading = false;
 }
}
```